# How can I manage Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, maintenance

I have installed Visual Studio Express 2013 some time ago, and now I want to manage components that VS installed with.

Remembering that installing VS takes hours of a life time - is there a quick way to add and remove installed components of Visual Studio? - instead of reinstalling it.

---

To be precise I want to add Visual Studio Tools for Office but I cannot find a proper stand-alone installer. I know that VS Enterprise 2015 lets you choose to add VSTO to the installation and I guess VS Express 2013 does the same. At least I want to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no managing tool for Visual Studio Express 2013 because there are no custom options in Visual Studio Express 2013 setup.

About the VSTO - (at least for VS 2013 and VS 2015) it is available only for Professional or above versions.